# Using Java Optional.ofNullable effectively

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

I can extract a particular section using Java8 like below

```
request.getBody()
       .getSections()
       .filter(section -> "name".equals(section.getName))
       .findFirst();
```

But how do I do the same using optional in a **single line**. I might have body or sections null.

I tried the below but not working

```
Optional.ofNullable(request)
        .map(Request::getBody)
        .map(Body::getSections)
        .filter(section -> "name".equals(section.getName)) //compliation error. section is coming as a list here
        .findFirst();
```

I am not able to get this working in a single line. I tried doing flatMap but not working as well. Please advise if we can achieve this in a singe line.

Below is the complete schema for reference

```
class Request {
    Body body;

    public Body getBody() {
        return body;
    }

    public void setBody(Body body) {
        this.body = body;
    }

}

class Body {
    List<Section> sections;

    public List<Section> getSections() {
        return sections;
    }

    public void setSections(List<Section> sections) {
        this.sections = sections;
    }

}

class Section {
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

Comment: Replace `.filter(section -> "name".equals(section.getName)).findFirst();` with `.flatMap(sections -> sections.stream() .filter(section -> "name".equals(section.getName())).findFirst());`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to convert from `Optional` which represents a single value, to a `Stream` to finish with the `filter` and `findFirst()` operations. At least one way is to map to an empty `Stream` (or empty `List` as in the neighbouring answer) in case of any nulls:

```
Optional.ofNullable(request)
    .map(Request::getBody)
    .map(Body::getSections)
    .map(List::stream)
    .orElse(Stream.empty())
    .filter(section -> "name".equals(section.getName))
    .findFirst();
```

Comment: Now I understand. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

This should work for you:

```
Optional.ofNullable(request)
    .map(Request::getBody)
    .map(Body::getSections)
    .orElse(Collections.emptyList())
    .stream()
    .filter(section -> "name".equals(section.getName))
    .findFirst();
```